# Nodemailer using godaddy password

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, godaddy-api

Hello I have purchased email ID from godaddy for my application and its working fine but I have security concern to adding emailID's password in code , If I am using gmail they provide  application password instead of email ID's password

So is there a way/option to get a application password from godaddy instead of adding email ID password ?

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
     service: 'Godaddy',
     host: "smtpout.secureserver.net",
     secureConnection: true,
     port: 465,

     auth: {
        user: "customer@domain.com",
        pass: "emailPassword" // LOOKING FOR APPLICATION PASSWORD HERE
     }
  });
```

Comment: You may be better suited with an email sending service api like Sendgrid or AWS ses. These apis are designed for automated email sending and will provide better security and authentication than adding a fixed password to environment (don’t add it to your code as that may get committed)

Comment: I have tried AWS SES but they are not accepting production request @wanderingcode